# iPhone 3.0 beta 5 update: "ERROR: updating baseband: fls could not be verified"

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to update my iPhone to the 3.0 beta 5 OS, but I get this error at the end of the update process:

ERROR: updating baseband: fls could not be verified

The phone then goes to the pink "Connect to iTunes" screen.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks...

Comment: Careful not to violate the NDA regarding OS 3.0. Can't answer this.

Comment: you should post this comment to the developer forums on apple if you are a registered developer.  All 3.0 stuff is under NDA

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: well, I'm an iPhone developer and would like to use the iPhone to test my apps on 3.0 as requested by Apple.

Comment: -1: Go to http://devforums.apple.com/ to ask questions about the iPhone 3.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happened either because

1. I tried to update the iPhone software using Organizer
2. Restored the iPhone on my development machine instead of the machine that the iPhone syncs to

I finally figured out how to fix it. I used iTunes on the machine where the iPhone is synced to, and restored it to 2.2.1 OS. To do this, I had to put the iPhone in DFU mode, and shift click (Windows) in iTunes on the Restore button and select the 2.2.1 .ipsw.

Once the iPhone was restored, I updated the phone to the 3.0 OS by shift clicking on the Check Updates button in iTunes and selecting the 3.0 OS from the file browser.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the same issue, although I
>   can't seem to find a copy of the old
>   2.2.1 .ipsw file. Any ideas where I can find this? I have looked
>   everywhere in the developer areas on
>   apple site. Can find the sdk but not
>   the .ipsw....

Try to press the "Restore" button on iTunes. It shoud start to download the latest firmware version (2.2.1) for you.

Comment: Should have replied on PCa. Don't use the "Answer" options for that.